# In Eclipse (3.6) how can I disable the NLS unused/missing message entries in the console?

Tags: eclipse

When I switched from 3.4 to 3.6 recently I noticed many more messages that are displayed in the console during a run/debug than previously.  The most pervasive is the NLS unused message and NLS missing message.

I am wondering if there is a way to turn off the reporting of those messages, besides actually removing the unused messages and adding in the missing messages.  I have scoured the preferences (Window->Preferences), but have been unable to find one that corresponds to it.

I suppose it isn't terrible, but when using System.out.println(...) to push debug statements in to the console while running the product or executing unit tests it can be cumbersome to read through the unwanted messages looking for my debug statements.  Not impossible, but definitely cumbersome.

Any thoughts would be helpful on this matter.  Thanks!

Regards,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use System.err.println(...) to print debug statements, they show up in red in the console so they can be easily seen.

Comment: Fair enough, though I still might have to scroll through a large amount of messages before I encounter the red statements.  While it does make the task easier, it would be nice to turn off those messages.

Answer (score 0):

I use an excellent plugin called **GREP Console**, through which I can get certain texts highlighted, thus I can quickly identify the information that interests me. Maybe it could be helpful for what you need (you can highlight in white both foreground and background for the undesired patterns).

> To install Grep Console from the Update Site, select Help/Software
>   Updates/Available Software from your Eclipse menu and click Add Site
>   to add the following URL:
>
> http://eclipse.musgit.com
>
> You can now open the site in the list of available software, check
>   Grep Console and click Install to begin the installation process.

[image: screenshot]

You can get more information here: http://marian.musgit.com/projects_grepconsole.php

Comment: Thanks, I will have to check this out.  I'm always on the lookout for interesting and helpful tooling.